# Use different prefixes in spring boot @Configuration/@ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have spring boot app, and `.yaml` file with such configuration:

```
storage:
  path: C:\\path\\example
cache:
  durtion: 60
```

I need ONE class, that will contain both cache and storage. I thought that @ConfigurationProperties will help me, but the only thing I can do with this annotation is creating two different classes:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "storage")
public class ConfigA(){
     @Getter
     @Setter
     private String path;
}
...

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cache")
public class ConfigB(){
     @Getter
     @Setter
     private int duration;
}
```

How can I combine `ConfigA` and `ConfigB` in one class?
Is it possible to it without using `@Value`?
Update:
I've managed to do something like this, but I'm not sure this is the best way:

```
@Configuration
public class ValuesConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cache")
    public Cache cache(){
        return new Cache();
    }

    @Component
    public static class Cache{
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private int duration;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a 'global' config with no prefix, SpringBoot will try to fulfil it from the 'root' of all the properties

```java
public class StorageConfig(){
     @Getter
     @Setter
     private String path;
}

public class CacheConfig(){
     @Getter
     @Setter
     private int duration;
}

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
public class GlobalConfig(){
     @Getter
     @Setter
     private StorageConfig storage;
     @Getter
     @Setter
     private CacheConfig cache;
}
```

As you annotate your configs with `@Component` they are injectable as any other component so you just have to inject to access the properties they hold.